# How do I select the NEXT <td> element?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse some HTML using the HTML Agility Pack. The following code snippet selects the table element containing the information I need but I need to dig deeper into the table.

Once I have the InnerHtml of the table, I plan to look for a `<td>` with an innertext value of "Field #2", for example. But, then, I need to select the innertext of the NEXT `<td>`. I need the value 110, in this example. How do I do that?

```
foreach (var x in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[contains(@class,'data')]"))
{
     // psuedo code - search for td and use "contains" on the inner text / html.
     // Then, grab the next td inner html.

     Console.WriteLine(x.InnerHtml);
}


  <tr>
    <td width="158"><strong>Field #1:</strong></td>
    <td  width="99">1</td>
    <td  width="119"><strong>Field #2:</strong></td>
    <td  width="176">110</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="158"><strong>Field #3:</strong></td>
    <td  width="99">85</td>
    <td  width="119"><strong>Field #4:</strong></td>
    <td  width="176">-259.34</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="158"><strong>Field #5:</strong></td>
    <td  width="99">1</td>
    <td  width="119"><strong>Field #6:</strong></td>
    <td  width="176">110</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="158"><strong>Field #7:</strong></td>
    <td  width="99">12</td>
    <td  width="119"><strong>Field #8:</strong></td>
    <td  width="176">123.23</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code will return you desired td row.

```
//<td  width="176">110</td>
var td = x.SelectNodes("//td").SkipWhile(g => !g.InnerText.Contains("Field #2:")).Select(s => s).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the agility pack supports it, but in XPath you can query for the next sibling by using `/following-sibling`:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
    "//table[contains(@class,'data')]/tr/" +
       "td[/strong/text()='Field #2:']" + 
       "/following-sibling:td");
```

essentially - find all of the `td` nodes with the given text, and give me it's next sibling `td` node.

Comment: almost correct, there needs to be a '.' before the '/strong/' and after 'following-sibling' there have to be two ':'. Then it works just fine.